# Illegal left hand side of blocking assignment

Tags: verilog

I am new to verilog. I am writing the code for a 10x16 Round-Shift register. Can you help me with the error and also if any optimizations can be done?

```
module shift_reg_v(
    output [15:0] word_out
);

integer i;
integer j;

reg [159:0] coeff;
reg [15:0] word;

initial
begin
    for (i=0;i<160;i=i+1)
    begin   
        coeff[i] = 0;
    end

    for (i=0;i<16;i=i+1)
    begin   
        word[i] = 0;
    end
end

always
begin
for (j=0;j < 10;j = j+1)
begin
    for (i=0;i < 16;i = i+1)
    begin
        if (j==0)
        begin
            word[i] = coeff[(16*(j+1))+i];
        end
        else
        begin
            coeff[(16*j)+i] = coeff[(16*(j+1))+i];
        end
    end     
end

coeff[159:144] = word[15:0];
word_out[15:0] = word[15:0];

end
endmodule
```

The program is showing 2 errors at the output line: 
`word_out[15:0] = word[15:0];`

Comment: Is it your verilog code? If im not wrong!!

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for not mentioning that clearly.

Answer (score 6):

Referring to error:

> **Error**-[IBLHS-NONREG] Illegal behavioral left hand side 
>   a.sv, 42
>   **Non reg type** is not valid on the **left hand side** of this assignment
>   The offending expression is : word_out[15:0]
>   Source info: word_out[15:0] = word[15:0];

The **LHS** of any **procedural assignment statement** must be of `reg` type. Procedural assignment statements assign values to `reg`, `integer`, `real`, or `time` variables and can not assign values to `wire`. Note that `reg` can **hold or store** some value depending on some triggering event, while `wire` *cannot* store any value.

Make `word_out` as `reg` as follows:

```
module shift_reg_v(
    output reg [15:0] word_out
);
```

Referring to the warning:

> **Warning**-[PALF] Potential always loop found 
>   a.sv, 24
>   This always block has **no event control or delay statements**, it might
>   cause    an **infinite loop** in simulation.

Moreover, you have **not** given any sensitivity for `always` block execution. This might result in infinite loop. There is **no triggering control** for `always` block. Henceforth the block shall execute infinitely.

Use `always @(*)` (or `always_comb` in SystemVerilog) for **automatic sensitivity list** in combinational logic.

As a **side note**, you might have a `clk`, as **clocking input** to the module and make the `always` block work on the **edge of clock**. This will help in modelling sequential logic. (Note the usage of nonblocking assignments `<=` in case of sequential logic).

Refer [this PDF](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs150/Documents/Nets.pdf) for difference between reg and nets.Also, this [always block](http://www.eet.bme.hu/~nagyg/mikroelektronika/Always.pdf) might be useful.

Comment: WARNING:Xst:646 - Signal <word> is assigned but never used. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:653 - Signal <coeff<15:0>> is used but never assigned. This sourceless signal will be automatically connected to value 1010101010101010.

can anyone help me with this warning please?

Comment: The `coeff[15:0]` is never used. In the `always` block, when `j=0` then the `if` condition is selected and `coeff[15:0]` is never assigned. Henceforth the warning.

Comment: I made changes in order to assign value to coeff[15:0], but the warnings remains. I have removed the else statement. Please suggest.
         `if (j==0)`
     `begin`
         `word[i] = coeff[(16*(j+1))+i];` 
     `end`
     `coeff[(16*j)+i] = coeff[(16*(j+1))+i];`

Comment: could you help? `@sharvil111`

Comment: In order to better understand the error/warning, you might post a new question.

Answer (score -1):

Also, you need to correct following code :-

`coeff[i] = 0;`

It is a bit assignment and  should clearly specify that as coding practice.

`coeff[i] = 'h0;`

Comment: If i don't want to give fill `coeff[i] = i`, how can I do the bit assignment in that case?