# Verilog HDL error: Illegal left-hand side assignment

Tags: verilog, hdl

I am learning CPU Design and basic Verilog HDL. I have a processor running in tkgate on Fedora 29 and I have designed a hardware RAM disk. I can't test the RAM but have decided to replace it with an HDL RAM disk. Whenever I try to simulate the circuit, I get the error:
**RAM_HDL, line 17: Illegal use of 'w7' in left-hand-side assignment.**
Here is my code for the RAM:

```
module RAM_HDL(RAM, Data_In, Data_Out, Address, RW);  
    reg [15:0] RAM [127:0];  
    wire [15:0] Data_In;  
    wire [15:0] Data_Out;  
    wire [7:0] Address;  
    wire RW;  

    initial  
        $readmemb("RAM_DATA.BIN", RAM);  

    always @(*)  
        begin  
            if (RW)  
                RAM[Address] <= Data_In;  
            Data_Out <= Address;  
        end  

   endmodule
```

The error is on line 17:

```
Data_Out <= Address;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illegal left hand side of blocking assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159794/illegal-left-hand-side-of-blocking-assignment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code compiles at least:

```
module RAM_HDL(Data_In, Data_Out, Address, RW);

reg [15:0] RAM [127:0];    
input [15:0] Data_In;  
output [15:0] Data_Out;  
input [7:0] Address;  
input RW;  

initial  
  $readmemb("RAM_DATA.BIN", RAM);  

always @(*)  
  begin  
    if (RW)  
      RAM[Address] <= Data_In;  
  end  
assign Data_Out = RAM[Address];  

endmodule
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `Data_Out = RAM[Address]`? What's the point in RAM that doesn't return the data it stores :)

Comment: I did, sorry. There's no copy and paste in my editor so I had to copy by eye. Edited to reflect.

Answer (score 3):

I believe one of your problems is trying to assign to a wire type in an always block. Try changing the declaration of Data_Out to reg instead of wire. The 2 following examples compiled for me:

```
module RAM_HDL(Data_In, Data_Out, Address, RW);  
reg [15:0] RAM [127:0];  
input wire [15:0] Data_In;  
output reg [15:0] Data_Out;  
input wire [7:0] Address;  
input wire RW;  

initial  
    $readmemb("RAM_DATA.BIN", RAM);  

always @(*)  
    begin  
        if (RW)  
            RAM[Address] <= Data_In;  
        Data_Out <= Address;  
    end  

endmodule
```

note the changes. input and output are declared on the ports. The ram array is not one of the ports and the data_out is a reg.

another option would be to move the assignment of data out outside the always block and keep it as a wire:

```
module RAM_HDL(Data_In, Data_Out, Address, RW);  
reg [15:0] RAM [127:0];  
input wire [15:0] Data_In;  
output wire [15:0] Data_Out;  
input wire [7:0] Address;  
input wire RW;  

initial  
    $readmemb("RAM_DATA.BIN", RAM);  

always @(*)  
    begin  
        if (RW)  
            RAM[Address] <= Data_In;    
    end  
assign Data_Out = Address;

endmodule
```

the changes are mostly the same. the input output declarations and the ram array is removed from the port list. Data_Out however is now assigned outside the always block so it can stay a wire.

Comment: I changed the Data_Out variable from wire to reg. I now get the following error:
Motherboard: Invalid type declaration used on port Data_Out

Comment: Further added input/output as appropriate to the wire/reg definitions. So my code/syntax is the same as yours. Now get the error:
Line2: Syntax error.

Comment: @JohntheAlmost-Genius I just edited the answer to hopefully address those problems. and give an alternate option if reg for some reason doesn't work.

Comment: More errors on lines: 3, 14, 15 & 18. All reporting syntax error.

Comment: And lines 4, 6, 15 & 16 for the 2nd example.

Comment: @JohntheAlmost-Genius Create a new reg in the module and assign Address to that (using <=). Make Data_Out a wire and assign that to the new reg. Then Data_Out will still be a wire and you will not have the original issue.